# Install-Package SignalR causes Unable to find package 'SignalR'

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

I'm trying to install SignalR package via NuGet but it doesn't see one:

```
PM> Install-Package SignalR
Install-Package : Unable to find package 'SignalR'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package SignalR
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was renamed to `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR`. For more details see http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2012/11/11/microsoft-asp-net-signalr.aspx

Search for:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
```

... but make sure "Include Prerelease" is selected at the top of the window.

Comment: Or in the Package Manager Console use the command: `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -IncludePrerelease`